# What type of state is glClearColor?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

Does it belong to framebuffer object state?  Is it shareable context state?  Is it non-shareable context state?

I just can't find it in the specs :=(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The clear color is context state.

There's no such thing as "shareable" context state; state in an OpenGL context is never shared with other contexts. *Objects* can be shared, but not context state.

Comment: If I have an editor with like 3 contexts - one for rendering swatches, 2 for displaying some viewports.  All of them share whatever is shareable.  So does that mean each context's glClearColor value may be different and is not affected in one context if with another context being current, glClearColor is called?

Comment: I'm not sure how I can be more clear. In OpenGL, *objects* are shared between contexts. Those are the only things that are shared (and even then, [not all objects](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Object#Object_Sharing)). The clear color isn't an object and therefore is not shared.

Comment: You were clear in the first place - I just wanted to double-check.  Thank you very much!